# php Highlight multiple word

Tags: php, highlight

I want to high light multiple word

I want to search for all search terms even if they overlap.

If I search ab and bc abc will be highlight

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually ask. Is this question about searching or about highlighting? Please take the time to revise your question and explain in more details what it actually is you want to do.

Comment: If you want to highlight ab word, Then apply css for span

Comment: I change question @arkascha

Answer (score 1):

```
Use this line of code which helps to highlights the search string:
<?php
function highlightsWords($text, $words) {
  preg_match_all('~\w+~', $words, $m);
  if(!$m) return $text;
  $re = '~\\b(' . implode('|', $m[0]) . ')\\b~i';
  return preg_replace($re, '<b>$0</b>', $text);
}

$text = 'Hang Seng Index advanced 0.6% to 24,400.80, after falling as much as 0.4% earlier';
$words = 'hang earlier';
echo highlightsWords($text, $words);
?>
```

Comment: Good approach, it will fail for partly words, though, as requested.

Comment: Also you'd need to quote the search words to prevent the regular expression breaking.

Answer (score 0):

You may look for **TextFeatures::highlightWords** in
https://github.com/Alex-K-O-R/Text-utilities

It has 2 strict and 2 optional parameters:

```
        TextFeatures::highlightWords(
          $sourceString, 
          $arrayOfWordsToHighlight, 
          $leftMarker,
          $rightMarker
        );
```

Method does dealing correct with partly words.